# 2004 Vitz door/trunk control(ler?) problem

Tags: toyota, electronic-control-module, computer, trunk, solenoid

I have a 2004 Vitz which uses a key with built in 1 button remote. This remote is supposed to unlock the doors and allow the boot switch to operate. (Car is started with a regular key)

The doors work fine, but my trunk does not unlatch (I need to get in manually from back seat to pull latch in trunk - there is no cable) . While the problem might be related to the catch, I suspect/postulate there is also control circuitry which has locked a possibly failing solenoid.

I've received 2 pieces if advice, and I would be grateful if anyone can comment or provide more info on the veracity of either of the following statements -

1. The trunk control is separate to the door controls - ie a low resistance/failing door control can't affect the trunk latch. (this makes sense to me)
2. There is no controller/computer controlling the boot latch - it's just a relay. This does not seem right to me). If it is a relay, any idea where the relay lives? If it's wrong - where can I find the control module [which I suspect is related to the remote]

Assuming there is a controller, is it likely that it has a lockout after a few failed open attempts, and how do I reset this? (Initially the trunk latch failed but playing on the drivers door console switches on the drivers door panel while car was running fixed it. This no longer works, and I suspect some kind of lockout/protection circuit has kicked in, but I've no evidence or place to look)